# How to use json.nl arrmap with facet.missing=true

Tags: solr, facet

Whenever I use the `json.nl=arrmap` parameter with the `facet.missing=true`, I get the error below:

```
"message": "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map",
    "messages": [
        "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
    ]
```

Can both be used together? I don't want to use another json.nl option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `facet.missing=true` with `json.nl=arrmap` (with `json.nl=map` as well) is problematic because the missing facets precisely don't have any key (facet value is missing) so their count isn't mapped as the "regular" facets, ie. :

```
[{"facet_value_1": <count_1>}, {"facet_value_2": <count_2>}, <count_missing>]
```

When the error says `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map`, it means `count_missing` is a scalar value while it expects a `(key, value)` pair.

You can use `json.nl=arrntv` instead, which is more verbose but should prevent this issue.